# Why is this a valid proof for the harmonic series?

Tags: calculus, integration, divergent-series

The other day, I encountered the Harmonic series which I though is an interesting concept. There were many ways to prove that it's divergent and the one I really liked was rather simple but did the job nevertheless. But a proof used integrals and proved that it diverges. But when using integrals, aren't we also calculating fractions with a decimal denominator? I'm not really familiar with calculus and usually only do number theory but doesn't integral find the area under a continuous curve?
Thanks in advance for any help!
**EDIT** Here's the integral proof:
$$\int_1^{\infty} 1 / x \,dx= {\infty}$$

Comment: It would really help us if you included the proof in question...

Comment: @EeveeTrainer my question isn't about a proof for the Harmonic series. I know it diverges using comparison test and fully understand it. But why does the integral work? Here's the comparison test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test. **EDIT** I just realized you meant the integral proof! I'm so sorry, I'll add it.

Comment: Your textbook probably has the "integral test" ... look in the index for that.

Comment: Because the function is decreasing so for example on $[1,2]$, $1 \ge \frac{1}{x}$, on $[2,3]$, $\frac{1}{2} \ge \frac{1}{x}$ etc; integrating and summing on $n$ we get the result

Comment: The mathematics required to prove that the integral test actually works is **much** more difficult than the mathematics requires in the simple proof that the harmonic series diverges. So you shouldn't have the impression that the integral test ultimately yields a simpler proof. That said, you also should learn to be able to use the integral test, because sometimes it is easier to use than other techniques. And if you have the time you should learn the **proofs** of the basic theorems about integrals that underlie the proof of the integral test given in *forgottenarrow*'s answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following summation:

$$
A=1\cdot 1+\frac12\cdot1+\frac13\cdot1+\frac14\cdot1+...
$$

That's a sum of the areas of an infinite number of rectangles of height $\frac1n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and width 1. Do you agree that's nothing more than the harmonic series? Moreover, the area under the curve $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is clearly less than $A$ and lies totally within $A$ (see the picture below). However, the area under the curve $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ from $1$ to $\infty$ doesn't add up to a finite number. It goes to infinity. What should be happening with a piece of area that's even larger than that? Obviously, it must also be infinite. Therefore, the harmonic series diverges.

[image: integral test]

Answer (score 6):

It works using a simple inequality. If $f(x) \leq M$ for $x \in [a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \leq M(b-a)$. This is fairly easy to prove:

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \leq \int_a^b M\,dx = M(b-a).$$

Notice that $1/x < 1/n$ on the interval $[n,n+1]$. Then,

$$\infty = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+1} \frac{1}{x}\,dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}.$$

Comment: The theorem as you state it is valid only for finite sums. However, you use it for an infinite sum in your explanation. As I'm sure you're aware, this doesn't always follow.

Comment: Which theorem do you mean specifically?

Comment: I was referring to the inequality; I thought I saw an interchange of $\sum$ and $\int,$ but now that I look closely, I see that I must have been dreaming, or something else was the case. You've simply added up infinitely many such inequalities -- nothing harmful in that at all. Whereupon, your well-earned upvote. It's a shame that OP got carried away by pictures, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good thing to look out for and an easy mistake to make. Thanks!

Comment: Slight nitpick not worth an edit unless something else is added, but it should be $1/x\le1/n$ instead of $1/x<1/n$ or the intervals should be switched to being open.

Comment: @Allawonder I upvoted both answers but the main reason that I accepted the other answer is because as I mentioned, I'm not really familiar with calculus so that answer was easier for me to understand and although the easiest solution isn't always the best solution, that was enough for me.

Comment: @BornaGhahnoosh In this case, the easiest is *not* the best. This one is more rigorous and makes you see why it works, only if you invest a little time to understand it. And there's no special calculus here except integrating a constant function, which is trivial. Everything else is doing comparisons, and addition. I don't know the type of number theory you do, but sooner or later you might like to dip in the analytic brand -- then you cannot escape inequalities and calculus. Also, see *user 2180's* comment under the comment of OP.